# Layouts and maps

Tags: susy

I have a project which has different layouts at various breakpoints and I'm struggling a little to get the maps part to work. I've set up an example at http://sassmeister.com/gist/ef02247af9f901fb3897

You'll see i have two maps and each has different grid settings and debug colours. But I have a few issues:

1. Grid colours aren't changing. They aren't even shown for the first map (which should be yellow and then red for the wider grid).
2. Although the grid columns change, i don't think the column widths or the gutter widths are correct. As an example column ONE seems to be bigger than the grid fifth column when it should be just a bit shorter and the margin doesn't seem to be wider either. Could this just be the grid background not being accurate enough?
3. When I reach the 975 breakpoint the gutter should get larger than what was defined in tablet map but it doesn't appear to be.

Any ideas as to what is needed to get the correct map to run at different breakpoints. Do I need to clear / reset the map at various breakpoints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on with the grid-image colors. That seems like a bug. Can you file an issue on GitHub?

The other two problems are related to how you apply your grid settings. As far as Susy is concerned, your grids are only being used for the containers (where you pass them in explicitly). Susy doesn't know anything about the DOM or nesting of elements, so those grid settings aren't "passed on" to the children in any real way.

There are a few ways to tell the `span` mixins what grid settings to use. you can pass them in explicitly e.g. `@include span(last 7 of $tablet);`, or you could use the `with-layout` mixin to wrap a whole group:

```
  @include breakpoint(760px) {
    @include with-layout($tablet) {
      @include container;
      .column1 {
        @include span(5);
      }
      .column2 {
        @include span(last 7);
      }
    }
  }
```

Or you can use `susy-breakpoint`, which is a shortcut for exactly that:

```
  @include susy-breakpoint(760px, $tablet) {
    @include container;
    .column1 {
      @include span(5);
    }
    .column2 {
      @include span(last 7);
    }
  }
```

I'm not adding context to the containers or the spans, because Susy will assume the default global context, which is being set by `with-layout` and `susy-breakpoint` in these examples.